# Ubuntu server disk space extended

Tags: ubuntu

On vmware server i have a ubuntu server running. I have add 45G for disk space. But i don't think the linux server is using the hole disk space only 25G.
Sda2 need to be extended.

```
root@:~# sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE  SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda             45G
├─sda1 vfat    512M /boot/efi
├─sda2 ext4   21.5G /
└─sda3 swap      8G [SWAP]
sr0           1024M
root@:~#
```

When i look at cfdisk i see this:

```
 Device                          Start               End           Sectors             Size Type
>>  Free space                       2048              2048                 0               0B                              /dev/sda1                        2048           1050623           1048576             512M EFI System
    /dev/sda2                     1050624          46141439          45090816            21.5G Linux filesystem
    /dev/sda3                    46141440          62912511          16771072               8G Linux swap
    Free space                   62912512          62914526              2015          1007.5K
```

Does it use the full space?  If not, what do i need to do for extending it?

Comment: You have only _1007.5K_ free space on this device.

Comment: oke but why does sda say 45G when i count sda1,sda2,sda3 it's only 29G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get a gparted ISO.  Other distro have it as well.

Connect it to this VM, and use it to view the size of the disk. If it says you only have 25gb of space then you have not successfully increased the size of the volume to 45gb.

I usually go into the settings of the VM first and increase the size there. Then I can use gparted to resize the partitions after rebooting.